# FlyWay : log show successfully table created but failed to create Table?

Tags: java, database-migration, flyway, baseline

Running SQL script on Oracle database with Spring Boot and FlyWay on shows successful log result, but fails to create the tables. 
The only thing which is being created in the database is the flyway_history table which has in it an item with the value <>
Deleting the row and restarting the application solves the problem. Where can be the problem, can't really understand. Disabling the baseline option in Spring Boot application does not affect on it.
An help from a professional would appreciate.

[image]

Comment: would you please add some logs to dictate the problem to a specific.

Comment: The log says the version have been migrated successfuly. No script failure, no exception unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the baseline version you set is incorrect. What the log is showing is the baseline version, which is NOT being executed. Only versions added after the baseline are usually executed. Hope that helps!